# Import Action Script File in a Flex Project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'm learning Flex and I've just found this nice [effect](http://www.riacodes.com/flash/horizontal-photo-gallery-with-hover-zoom-effect/comment-page-1/#comment-168781). Would it be possible to import it in Flex?
Thanks in advance.
Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'll need one of 2 things:

1. Enough knowledge of the similarities and differences between Flash and Flex to be able to translate the instructions for making MovieClips and TextFields to using Flex components such as Box and Label. If you have that, you probably wouldn't have asked the question.
2. Someone who has that knowledge who is willing to explain the differences.

I can be quite patient and verbose when I haven't had a bad day, but today I have. I didn't want to leave your question completely unanswered, but the answer of "yes" probably won't get you too far without a lot of explaining.